# Cross-device python execution going wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So I have an image treatment program, and I worked on it on a Win7 desktop. One of it's functions is changing the contrast of the image the user chooses. It works fine on the Win7 desktop, but when I transfer it to my laptop on Win10, it makes an overflow on the red value.
This is the result on the Win10 laptop:

[image: wrong obama]

And this is the one on Win7 desktop:

[image: good obama]

This is the function that changes the constrast:

```
def change_contrast(level):

    img = Image.open(a)
    img.load()

    factor = (259 * (level+255)) / (255 * (259-level))
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            color = img.getpixel((x, y))
            new_color = tuple(int(factor * (c-128) + 128) for c in color)
            img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)

    return img
```

Here is the full code in case you need it:

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as Tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog, DISABLED, messagebox as tkMessageBox
import os
import ntpath
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter
import PIL
from collections import Counter
from random import randint
import random
import PIL.ImageOps


def EchelleDeGris():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            if type(p)==int:
                p=(p,p,p)
            o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
            px1[x,y]=(o,o,o)
    Ima2.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def SupprimerImage():
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=imt)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def Luminosite():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            if type(p)==int:
                p=(p,p,p)
            px1[x,y]=(p[0]+S1.get(),p[1]+S1.get(),p[2]+S1.get())
    Ima2.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def AnnulerModifications():
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im1)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def get_pixel(pixels, x, y):
    try:
        return pixels[x, y]
    except IndexError:
        return None


def get_neighbors(pixels, x, y):
    neighbors = list()
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x, y - 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x, y + 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x - 1, y))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x + 1, y))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x - 1, y - 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x - 1, y + 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x + 1, y - 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x + 1, y + 1))
    return neighbors


def filter_art(pixels, size):
    indexes = dict()
    for x in range(size[0]):
        for y in range(size[1]):
            color = get_pixel(pixels, x, y)
            neighbors = get_neighbors(pixels, x, y)
            new_color = Counter(neighbors).most_common()[0][0]
            if new_color is not None:
                indexes[x, y] = new_color
    for x, y in indexes:
        pixels[x, y] = indexes[x, y]


def pop_art(path_orig, path_mod, coef):

    s=[]
    for i in range(9):

        r=(randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))
        g=(randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))
        b=(randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))

        image_orig = Image.open(path_orig)
        size = image_orig.size
        image_mod = Image.new("RGB",(size[0],size[1]))
        pixels_orig = image_orig.load()
        pixels_mod = image_mod.load()
        for x in range(size[0]):
            for y in range(size[1]):
                p = pixels_orig[x, y]
                if isinstance(p, int):
                    rgb = (p,p,p)
                elif isinstance(p, tuple) and len(p) in (3, 4):
                    rgb = p[:3]
                else:
                    raise TypeError('Unknown pallete')
                average_color = sum(rgb) / 3
                if average_color <= 85:
                    pixels_mod[x, y] = r
                elif 85 < average_color <= 170:
                    pixels_mod[x, y] = g
                elif average_color > 170:
                    pixels_mod[x, y] = b
        for _ in range(coef):
            filter_art(pixels_mod, size)
        image_mod.save(''+dir_path+'\\PopArt\\Modified Images\\result'+str(i)+'.png')
        Img=[None]*9
    for i in range(9):
        Img[i]=Image.open(""+dir_path+"\\PopArt\\Modified Images\\result"+str(i)+".png")
        basewidth = int(Img[i].size[1]/3)
        wpercent = (basewidth / float(Img[i].size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(Img[i].size[1]) * float(wpercent )))
        Img[i] = Img[i].resize((basewidth , hsize ), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
        Img[i].save(''+dir_path+'\\PopArt\\Resized Images\\resized_image'+str(i)+'.png')


    Img1=[None]*9
    pixels1=[None]*9
    Imaz=Image.new("RGB",(basewidth*3,hsize*3))
    pixels=Imaz.load()
    for i in range(9):
        Img1[i]=Image.open(''+dir_path+'\\PopArt\\Resized Images\\resized_image'+str(i)+'.png')
        pixels1[i]=Img1[i].load()


    for x in range(0,basewidth):
        for y in range(0,hsize):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[0][x,y]
        for y in range(hsize,hsize*2):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[1][x,y-hsize]
        for y in range(hsize*2,hsize*3):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[2][x,y-hsize*2]

    for x in range(basewidth,basewidth*2):
        for y in range(0,hsize):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[3][x-basewidth,y]
        for y in range(hsize,hsize*2):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[4][x-basewidth,y-hsize]
        for y in range(hsize*2,hsize*3):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[5][x-basewidth,y-hsize*2]

    for x in range(basewidth*2,basewidth*3):
        for y in range(0,hsize):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[6][x-basewidth*2,y]
        for y in range(hsize,hsize*2):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[7][x-basewidth*2,y-hsize]
        for y in range(hsize*2,hsize*3):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[8][x-basewidth*2,y-hsize*2]
    Imaz = Imaz.resize((size[0] , size[1] ), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    Imaz.save(""+dir_path+"\\PopArt\\Result Image\\result.png")


def usepop():
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\traitement.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)
    I2.update_idletasks()
    pop_art(a, None, coef=4)
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\PopArt\\Result Image\\result.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def change_contrast(level):

    img = Image.open(a)
    img.load()

    factor = (259 * (level+255)) / (255 * (259-level))
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            color = img.getpixel((x, y))
            new_color = tuple(int(factor * (c-128) + 128) for c in color)
            img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)

    return img

def use_contrast():
    result = change_contrast(S2.get())
    result.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def recherche_contours():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            if type(p)==int:
                p=(p,p,p)
            o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
            px1[x,y]=(o,o,o)
    Ima2 = Ima2.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
    image = Ima2
    if image.mode == 'RGBA':
        r,g,b,a = image.split()
        rgb_image = Image.merge('RGB', (r,g,b))

        inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(rgb_image)

        r2,g2,b2 = inverted_image.split()

        final_transparent_image = Image.merge('RGBA', (r2,g2,b2,a))

        final_transparent_image.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")

    else:
        inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(image)
        inverted_image.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

main=Tk()

main.withdraw()
a = filedialog.askopenfilename()
main.deiconify()

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("Test2.py"))

main.configure(background="#a1dbcd")
main.title("Photoshop Version.Megzari")

Ima1=Image.open(a)
z=Ima1.size
nux=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
nuxy=nux.load()
for x in range(z[0]):
    for y in range(z[1]):
        nuxy[x,y]=(255,255,255)
nux.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\Blank.png")


if z>(400,400):
    main.withdraw()
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Resolution Error", "The image is too big, please select a smaller one.")
    sys.exit()


elif z<(400,400):
    im1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=a)
    I1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im1)
    I1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan =3)
    imt = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\Blank.png")
    T1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=imt)
    T1.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)
    B1 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Echelle de gris", command = EchelleDeGris, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=NORMAL)
    B1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=0)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Appliquer Luminosité", command = Luminosite, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=1)
    S1 = Scale(main, from_=0, to=254, orient=HORIZONTAL, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", length = 200)
    S1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    B2 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Supprimer Image", command = SupprimerImage, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B2.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=7)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Annuler Modifications", command = AnnulerModifications, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=6)
    B4 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Pop Art", command = usepop, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B4.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=3)
    S2 = Scale(main, from_=-258, to=258, orient=HORIZONTAL, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", length = 200)
    S2.grid(row=2, column=4)
    B4 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Appliquer Contraste", command = use_contrast, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B4.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=4)
    B5 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Trouver Contours", command = recherche_contours, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B5.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=5)

    s=S1.get()
    s2=S2.get()




main.mainloop()
```

I don't know why it gives me a different result depending on the platform I'm running it from.

EDIT: Code that uses `PIL.ImageEnhance.Contrast`:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
image = Image.open('E:\Projet Complet\Images\obama.png')
contrast = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
contrast_applied=contrast.enhance(1)
image.show()
```

On the Win7 I have Python 3.2.5 and PIL 1.1.7,

And on the Win10 I have Python 3.4.5 and PIL 1.1.7

Comment: Any reason you are not using [`PIL.ImageEnhance.Contrast`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageEnhance.html#PIL.ImageEnhance.Contrast)?

Comment: In case you didn't notice, my code gets the scale value (`s2=S2.get()`) between `-258` and `258`, and creates a contrasted image depending on that value. With `PIL.ImageEnhance.Contrast` I can't seem to be able to adjust the level of contrast, it just gives me a single enhanced image.

Comment: It takes a floating point number from `0.0` to `1.0`.  Does that not provide leveling?

Comment: I added a piece of code that uses the function in the post, and the result image is not different from the original one, it's the exact same, unless I've done something wrong.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Is all that Tkinter code really necessary to replicate the problem?

Comment: I posted the snippet before the whole code you just have to replace `a` in the `img = Image.open(a)` with a file of yours. The complete code is just in case you want to check anything else that might be wrong with my code and that might be causing the problem without me noticing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way around this problem. Since I tried to write my own contrast function, some version differences end up giving this kind of result. So instead of having:

```
def change_contrast(level):

    img = Image.open(a)
    img.load()

    factor = (259 * (level+255)) / (255 * (259-level))
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            color = img.getpixel((x, y))
            if type(color) == int:
                color=(color,color,color)
                new_color = tuple(int(factor * (c-128) + 128) for c in color)
                new_color = new_color[0]
                img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)
            elif type(color) != int:
                new_color = tuple(int(factor * (c-128) + 128) for c in color)
                img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)
    return img

def use_contrast():
    result = change_contrast(S2.get())
    result.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)
```

You use this:

```
def change_contrast():

    image = Image.open(a)
    scale_value=S2.get()
    contrast = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
    contrast_applied = contrast.enhance(scale_value)
    contrast_applied.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)
```

And I replace the function in the button from `use_contrast` to just `change_contrast`. It's also much shorter and faster.
But for the second code, you have to write `from PIL import ImageEnhance`